# Delegate not working for google plus integration

Tags: ios

I am trying to implement google plus integration,sign in working properly,the problem is after sign in not entering in `- (void)finishedWithAuth` my coe follows:

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];

    signIn.clientID = @"CLIENT_ID";

    signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin,
                     nil];    
    signIn.delegate = self;
```

Already declared GPPSignInDelegate delegate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its the problem with checking call back url, plz check the redirect url in appdelegate

Comment: Can you illustrate more please :)

Comment: Just add this to app delegate
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                         annotation:annotation];
}